# Get gradle to automatically download dependencies for android project

Tags: android, build, gradle, android-studio

I have a java project in netbeans and by defining dependencies in the pom.xml file like so:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Quartz -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
        <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The specified dependency is downloaded and added automatically when i build the project.

Now, I'm working on an android project using android studio + the gradle build sysetem, but when i specify dependencies in my build.gradle file like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
}
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'http://repo.spring.io/snapshot'
    }
}
```

The dependencies don't get downloaded, and i have to manually add them.
Is it possible to have the dependencies downloaded automatically?
And if possible, how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to specify a repository that actually contains the Quartz library. The URL you declare does not contain it. You could use Maven Central if that's acceptable.

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.1.5'
}
```